# Adaptar proyecto Angular JS de otra persona en mi PC

Tags: angular

Mi compañero ha creado un proyecto con angular JS y me luego me paso la carpeta donde lo tiene montado. Bien, estoy ahora yo estoy intentando generar la carpeta dist para meterlo en producción pero mi terminal me da el siguiente error al introducir `ng build --prod`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco me deja arrancar el proyecto en local con `ng serve -o`. Me aparece el mismo error. ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que no es angularjs. Son dos cosas diferentes. Prueba hacer `npm install` antes de hacer el build.

Answer (score 2):

Es necesario que primero hagas un `npm install` para que se descarguen todas las librerias que el proyecto requiere.

> ## [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install#description)
>
> This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on. If the package has a package-lock or shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that, with an npm-shrinkwrap.json taking precedence if both files exist.
>
> ---
>
> Este comando installa un paquete, y cualquier otro paquete del que dependa. Si el paquete tiene un fichero package-lock o shrinwrap, la instalación de depencias será manejada por ellos, con npm-shrinkwrap.json tomando presedencia sobre ambos si el archivo existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso. Hacia falta hacer un npm install antes.